# Spring MVC Interceptor and Form Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application is based on Spring MVC and Spring Security 3.2.7 and I've an interceptor that I want to be executed for each path on my web application. 
So I've put in my xml config the following code:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="social.picnik.api.marketplace.multitenancy.interceptor.MongoMultitenantInterceptor">
            <property name="defaultTenantId" value="default"/>
        </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

It works fine for all my URLs but one: the login.

The login is performed by Spring Security with the login-form, the code is the following:

```
<security:form-login
                 authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
                 authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"
                 login-processing-url="/picnik-rest/login"
                 username-parameter="username" 
                 password-parameter="password"

/>
```

I skip the remaining configuration, but the login itself it's working.

The problem is that */picnik-rest/login* is not considered by my interceptor.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A Spring MVC interceptor is only invoked on requests that reaches Spring MVC. The entire Spring Security filter chain is called *before* Spring MVC. Requests to the login processing URL is handled by Spring Security and will never reach Spring MVC.

If you want an "interceptor" for every URL you can do a servlet filter and put it before Spring Security.